# MS Access Query using in the criteria > operator but the results are as if I used < operator?

Tags: ms-access-2016

This is the SQL Code for my query
`
SELECT tbl_salaries.Mobile_PK, Len([Mobile_PK]) AS Expr1

FROM tbl_salaries

WHERE (((Len([Mobile_PK]))>10));`

Result:

[image: Query Result Screenshot]

I dont know what is going wrong i was working with this database for 2 months with no problems all of a sudden all my queries with relational operators are inverted. NEED YOUR HELP

Answer (score 0):

Got an answer form MS Coomunity

Len function not to be used with Number field.

The direct approach is to use Mobile_PK>=1000000000

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).